# When (and more importantly, why) does $AA^T$ have an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix A that is m by n and m < n. For context, say I am interested in finding a vector $ \theta_z \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$ A^T \theta_z = \theta_x$$

i.e. we have more rows/"equations" than columns/"unknowns".

I was going to do it by multiplying both sides by A and then find the inverse of $AA^T$.

I was told that this only works when we have linearly independent rows. Is this suppose to be obvious? What is an intuitive way to explain this? Also, I am even more interested in a precise and rigorous proof if there is one.

I was also told that when the rows are dependent, then  the system has an infinite number of solutions. However, I was a little skeptical about this, because if we have more rows, then if we did some elimination on the original $ A^T \theta_z = \theta_x$, then we could have at most a rank of size $m$ (one for each column). Which could lead to only 1 solution or zero (none) but never to infinity. So I think that solutions is wrong, i.e. linearly independent rows if anything, shouldn't lead to more than 2 solutions ever, we should only have 1 or zero for the original system $ A^T \theta_z = \theta_x$. Is that correct?

Comment: If our matrices can have real or complex entries, and both $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ satisfy the equation $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, then shouldn't $\vec{x} = c_1\vec{x_1} + c_2\vec{x_2}$ also solve our equation, where $c_1 + c_2 = 1$? I'm not sure about the statement "shouldn't lead to more than 2 solutions ever".

Comment: @pjs36 What I meant was that $A^Tx = y$ if $m < n$ should only lead to either 1 or zero solutions and thats it. Isn't that correct if we have more rows than columns?

Comment: If $A$ is $n\times m$, then $^{\mathrm t}A$ is $m \times n$, so you can apply it to a vector in $\mathbf R^n$, not $\mathbf R^m$.

Comment: @Bernard that was a typo. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Pinocchio I was just pointing out that, if you've got 2 solutions and your matrices have entries from a suitable field, then you'll have an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the "precise and rigorous proof":

A (square) matrix has an inverse ("is invertible") if and only if it has linearly independent rows, if and only if it has linearly independent columns. Equivalently, the matrix $B$ has an inverse if and only if $Bx = 0$ implies $x = 0$, if and only if $x^TB = 0$ implies $x = 0$.

Suppose that $A$ has linearly dependent rows.  That is, there is a non-zero $x$ with $x^TA = 0$.  It follows that $x^T(AA^T) = (x^TA)A^T = 0A^T = 0$.  So, $AA^T$ also has linearly dependent rows, and therefore has no inverse.

Suppose that $A$ has linearly independent rows, so that $x^TA = 0 \implies x = 0$.  We now want to show that $x^TAA^T = 0 \implies x = 0$.  We have
$$
x^TAA^T = 0 \implies\\
(x^TAA^T)x = 0 \implies\\
(x^TA)(A^Tx) = 0 \implies\\
(x^TA) \cdot (x^TA) = 0 \implies\\
\|x^TA\|^2 = 0 \implies\\
x^TA = 0 \implies\\
x = 0
$$
So, $(AA^T)^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Actually, there is an unresolved issue. If $AA^T$ is NOT invertible, then how many solutions does $AA^T$ have? and how does that relate to the original columns of A.

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, the system $A \theta_z = \theta_x$ has either no solutions or infinitely many.  This also implies that $A^TA$ is not invertible.  However, the system
$$
A^TA \theta_z = A^T \theta_x
$$
Always has *at least* one solution; so if $A$ is not invertible, the second system will always have *infinitely many* solutions.

Comment: Why does it always have at least one solution?

Comment: The easiest way to see that is to note that the solution to the second system is always the [least squares solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29).  Even if there is no solution, there must be a vector that gets the closest to solving the equation.